# How do I install ant on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, homebrew, ant, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to OS X 10.9 Mavericks, ant is no longer on my path.

```
[126] 11:23:26 rkarl-mba-4:~/mobile-baselayer > ant
zsh: permission denied: ant
[126] 11:23:50 rkarl-mba-4:~/mobile-baselayer > which ant
ant not found
```

I tried installing through homebrew

```
[126] 11:23:09 rkarl-mba-4:~/mobile-baselayer > brew install ant
Error: No available formula for ant
```

It's odd that homebrew doesn't have a formula for that....

After googling, I found [this article](http://seventy6.com/post/14175174562/how-to-upgrade-apache-ant-to-1-8-2-on-osx-using), which suggested using a user's custom formula for brew.

```
[1] 11:23:56 rkarl-mba-4:~/mobile-baselayer > brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/ant.rb

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew\ 0.9.4\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-358;\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.9) https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/ant.rb -o /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/ant.rb
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It looks like the alternate repository was migrated. You can either enable the homebrew alternate repository or install directly after updating your brew:

```
brew update
brew install ant
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: `brew install homebrew/dupes/ant` also works.

Comment: as of today, you just need 
    brew install ant

Comment: Just as an aside: if you already have Homebrew installed (as I did, from a while back), make sure you perform a `brew update` before you try the accepted answer or else you may get a 404 error. It is good policy to update your formulas before install but I *might* have let that slip my mind...

Comment: I had 404 even after update. I've tried:
`brew tap homebrew/dupes` and then `brew install ant` and worked.
(Source: http://blog.xk72.com/post/53124504531/homebrew-dupes-installing-ant-on-mac-os-x )

Comment: @awenkhh But this gives `==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz. Error: Couldn't determine mirror. Try again later.` While the URL mentioned in that error message loads find in the browser.

Comment: To get around the issue mentioned in my previous message, I edited `/usr/local/Library/Formula/ant.rb` and replaced the URL there with `http://www.us.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz`. (Maybe `http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi` used to return a redirect, and it doesn't do this anymore?)

Comment: @Alessandro Vernet in doing so, you will have a conflict when running brew update. You should at least do a git -a commit 'your message' to have clean repo in /usr/local/Library/Formula

Comment: @awenkhh Good point. I just ran `git co ant.rb` afterwards, to clean up my changes, since I most likely won't need to run this in the future anymore.

Comment: It seems that homebrew does NOT create the needed (by some tools like cocos2dx-android) ant_path.

Comment: Install specific version (1.9):  
`brew install ant@1.9`

Answer (score 20):

Upgraded to Mavericks this morning and found "command not found: ant"

```
brew update
```

Ran the the update and then tried to install ant.

```
brew install ant
```

Ant was installed, but it also yeilded this alert:

> Warning: No developer tools installed. You should install the Command
>   Line Tools. Run `xcode-select --install` to install them.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Now, everything is running fine.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Homebrew, you can always download a binary distribution of Ant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi.  It works fine on OS X Mavericks.

Just download it, unzip/untar it, and add its `bin` directory to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence that worked for me:

```
xcode-select --install
brew update
brew install ant
```

Comment: It works, but I get: "Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available
Update them from Software Update in the App Store." but there are no updates on the app store.

Answer (score 3):

I usually install `ant` via [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). There is a pretty good [documentation](http://brew.sh/) .

Good luck.

Comment: That post doesn't even recommend itself anymore!

Comment: I followed the documentation and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had ant installed before upgrading to Mavericks. Afterwards, ant didn't work at all. The ONLY thing that worked for me was this:

brew uninstall ant

brew install ant