# Sublime Text with SuperAnt path is not correct

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, ant

Since upgrading to the latest Mac OSX (10.9.1) I cannot run builds in Sublime Text using the SuperAnt tool. Here is the error:

<> are my privacy omissions

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ant'
[cmd: ['ant', '-f', '/Users/stan/Development/<>/<>/build.xml', 'dist-amp']]
[dir: /Users/stan/Development/<>/<>]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

What I'm noticing is that my path listed in the error is not my actual path:

```
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/Users/stan/Development/tomcat7/ImageMagick/bin:/Users/stan/Development/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

So my question is two fold.

1. Were there changes in the latest OSX service pack that caused this issue to arise?
2. How can I manually set this path variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because Maverick does not have the Java tools anymore (like Maven, Ant, ...) pre-installed. What works for me whas:

```
brew update
brew install ant
```

Then, you might need to do the following to add the "ant" to the default path (that SuperAnt seems to be using)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant
```

Here are some links talking about the various ways to install Ant on Mac.

[How do I install ant on OS X Mavericks?](https://superuser.com/questions/610157/how-do-i-install-ant-on-os-x-mavericks)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495610/error-executing-command-ant-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks-when-building-for-andro